# Find and replacing two parts of a formula in each cell in a range

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to figure out how to find a replace each cells formula in a my range. The only issue with doing this manually is it is two seperate find a replaces in a vlookup on another workbook. This in turn does not work manually..
This is the code I have so far, but it is giving me an object required error, and I dont know if it will work as is.

[image: data]

```
 Sub Formula2()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

 ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("D3").End(xlToRight).Replace "4. Apr", "5. May", xlPart


 ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("D3").End(xlToRight).Replace "April", 
"May", xlPart


 Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True







 End Sub
```

Comment: The stuff in the square brackets is given to Excel's expression evaluation engine, which returns an error code because it doesn't understand VBA; because an error code isn't a `Range` object with a `Replace` method, VBA doesn't know what object to invoke this `Replace` member against, and throws an error saying "give me an object!" - Get rid of the square brackets.

Comment: I updated the code above but it doesnt seem to find a replace any of the cells formulas..any help?

Comment: The code runs but nothing seems to happen..

Answer (score 0):

Is the purpose of this to change the month of the financial folder it references?

If so there may be a another way, i.e. build that piece of the folder path in the vlookup using a date formatted by formula.

Its not a direct answer but may help.

Sorry wasn't able to do this as a comment

Comment: Yes that is the point, but the filepath  doesnt seem to allow me to enter in a formula as part of the filepath. If i concat it, then the vlookup doesnt seem to work. =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A3,'G:\Financial\Facility Work Papers and Financials\1. Operating Entities\Bridgeport\2. Financials\2018\4. Apr\[Bridgeport April 2018.xls]Trial Balance'!$A$30:$H$100,8,FALSE),0) this part doesnt work $A$30:$H$100,8,FALSE),0)

Comment: I figured a macro would work easier. I updated my formula in the main question above..it runs now, but does not change anything..